# Encoding ASCII character 0 terminate query string in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ascii, url-encoding, request.querystring

I received the encoded querystring which include ASCII Char 0 (`http://localhost/Test_Authentication.asp?token=%13%23%02%00%01%01%00%01%01%05%02%02%03%00%02%02%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A048`  ) and when I retrieve the value the string is terminated that position (`%00`). How should I fix this problem?

The following is my code.

```
Response.CharSet = "utf-8";
Session.CodePage=65001;

var strToken = (Request.QueryString("token").Count > 0)?Request.QueryString("token")(1):"";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%00 is ascii for null character. I suspect this is why the string is being terminated at this point.

I would suggest using a different format or method for your creating your hashed token, perhaps one that creates it as a hexidecimal value instead, e.g.;

```
B73A21FBCE3921E5DD0C935AB4D710DD
```

An MD5 hash is typically expressed as a 32-digit hexadecimal number. This will be far more friendly for passing around in querystring.

Comment: The likely-hood is that the token is already some form of hash.  An MD5 has doesn't define any encoding, its result is just an stream of bytes.   The real issue is that the data needs to be encoded as either Base64 or as in you example as Hex.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWJones. Amended answer to reflect your contribution